# python pandas: accessing datetime series for currency conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Panda dataframe as below:

```
>>> df.head()
            Date         From        To        Currency    Net
TransID
4569219     2015-02-21   Calzada     Michael   MXN         2396.0
5630763     2013-08-18   Juan        Edgar     USD         155.56
4698552     2013-08-17   David       Jessica   MXN         1965.23
5706840     2013-08-11   Edgar       Luis      MXN         923.22
7522850     2011-08-11   Jonathan    Juan      USD         58.23
```

The `Date` Series is `dtype: datetime64[ns]` and the `Net` one is `dtype: float64`.

And I want to convert any Mexican Pesos (MXN) Amount into USD, based on the exchange rate at the given date.

To do that I am using the `forex_python` library, for example:

```
>>> from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
... from datetime import datetime
...
... c = CurrencyRates()
... amount = 1000
... date = datetime(2013,02,21)
... print c.convert('MXN','USD', amount, date)
78.344
```

This converts 1000 MXN and returns the amount in USD. Now i want to apply this to my dataframe, but I get different types of errors. First, I have tried:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from datetime import datetime

c = CurrencyRates()
df.loc[df['Currency'].str.contains('MXN'), 'Net'] = c.convert('MXN', 'USD', df['Net'], df['Dates'])
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

After searching for the error here, I tried another way using the `dt` accessor:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from datetime import datetime

c = CurrencyRates()
df.loc[df['Currency'].str.contains('MXN'), 'Net'] = c.convert('MXN', 'USD', df['Net'], datetime(df['Date'].dt.year, df['Date'].dt.month, df['Date'].dt.day))
```

This time I get another error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>
```

I should underline that it works fine if I'm not using the date argument (but I get today's exchange rate). I.e.:

```
df.loc[df['Currency'].str.contains('MXN'), 'Net'] = c.convert('MXN', 'USD', df['Net'])
df['Currency'] = 'USD'
```

I would love my final result to be:

```
>>> df.head()
            Date         From        To        Currency    Net
TransID
4569219     2015-02-21   Calzada     Michael   USD         158.68
5630763     2013-08-18   Juan        Edgar     USD         155.56
4698552     2013-08-17   David       Jessica   USD         154.40
5706840     2013-08-11   Edgar       Luis      USD         923.22
7522850     2011-08-11   Jonathan    Juan      USD         72.53
```

It seams like I can't extract the corresponding date from the `Date` Series to use in my `c.convert()` function. I have no idea how to solve this problem without extracting my information and working with lists, which I honestly don't really want to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you tied to FOREX rates? Would https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter  be an option? NOTE: it provides slightly different historical rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for the `apply` which can loop through all your rows with `axis=1`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Net'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Net if x.Currency == 'USD' else 
                               c.convert('MXN', 'USD', x.Net, x.Date), axis=1)
df['Currency'] = 'USD'

              Date      From       To Currency         Net
TransID                                                   
4569219 2015-02-21   Calzada  Michael      USD  159.638292
5630763 2013-08-18      Juan    Edgar      USD  155.560000
4698552 2013-08-17     David  Jessica      USD  152.944025
5706840 2013-08-11     Edgar     Luis      USD   73.240889
7522850 2011-08-11  Jonathan     Juan      USD   58.230000
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :) !